# Index Match on 2 separate google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

Can you please help me with the index match formula with Google sheets on 2 different workbooks? I know the formula on a regular excel sheet but it just won't do the same with google sheets.

I tried the same formula with the regular excel sheet but it just won't work.

Comment: Have you tried using [`importrange`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/913)?

Comment: Hi! I've been trying to do the importrange formula but it doesn't seem to work....

Comment: this is the first workbook -- this is where the data comes from.... 
   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VYCPRlno-upguZFmf-dgVG8pXxkXXTx-OWt_VBv4d5c/edit#gid=0

Comment: this is the second workbook where I need a data from the first workbook to show up 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qwpbac9IEqPPbenQh0gRUm8nrcPQSDURqJY9ZzVTYJ0/edit#gid=0

Comment: sheets are private

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1VYCPRlno-upguZFmf-dgVG8pXxkXXTx-OWt_VBv4d5c", "Sheet1A:Z")
```

**note:** chenge sheet name if needed

**note2:** first you will see ref error. hover your cursor over it and a button will popup. click on it to authorize the connection/link between your two spreadsheets